# Name of special alert view iphone

Tags: iphone

I have been looking for the name of this UI element for a while now, but I cant come up with anything. What is the name of the round rect with 'Reloading Data' in it? I thought that I remembered using a view like this a while back, and there was some open source library that made its use much easier.

Screen shot of cydia.

[image: Cydia]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple API is private and cannot be used in AppStore apps. I and many others use MBProgressHUD: http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MBProgressHUD.

Comment: Perfect! MBProgressHUD was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Also check out on [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD) as a somewhat simpler alternative.

Comment: Also a good alternative. I will look into the pros and cons of each. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

It's [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

You will get more opensource controls on this [link](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=activity).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a UIActivityIndicator? It essentially provides the same utility without the need to implement 3rd party code? Do you really need any custom behavior the class does not already provide? The simpler the better you know..? ;)

Comment: I was looking for MBProgressHUD just because I have used it before (but forgot the name) and that it has different styles (activity indicator, success, failed, progress, etc.) This is one case where simpler may not be better :)